# Login system from different domains

Tags: java, php, authentication, oauth

the company I work has assigned me the task to create a system to login in every of the company products. These products are in different domains.

We want it to be like google. When we login to our mail account, we are automatically logged in in google+, google docs, youtube, etc.

The idea is to have a main application in Java, were all others, in PHP, would login to. Everytime a user goes to another company site, it will check the main application to see if a login has been made or to login that user. I was thinking about doing this with OAuth but as I read further I'm beggining to think that OAuth was not created for this.

How can I do this? Is there any example/library available on the web?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term you're looking for is [Single Sign On](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on).  One way to do this is using [SAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language).

Comment: The approach was SSO based (we changed the SSO we already had to support cross domain and improved it a bit).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple API, as one logs in, trigger it to send a request to another site and log them in and set their cookie.

Answer (score 0):

This can be slightly done by using the OAuth or you can go through your parent company too. Same like, we first login to gmail so we get session login to all the child sites like google doc, and etc. So, you can also go over the curl extension. Use it to login user to your child sites based over **BASIC** or **DIGEST** auth. system.

Comment: digestive auth? Sounds alimentary.

Comment: DIGESTIVE auth goes over md5 encrypted state.

Comment: You're thinking `DIGEST`. digestion is what goes on your stomach.

Comment: If we use the approach of using DIGEST then implementing it would be called DIGESTIVE method as per my knowledge sir!

Comment: It's 'digest authentication'. never 'digestive': http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt